# how can i change between two layers with revolution slider

Tags: wordpress, slider, mouseenter, mouseleave

Basically what i want is to change between two layers in rev slider that is one over the other.I want the first layer to trigger the second layer when the mouse enter the specific layer, and when the mouse leaves the layer i want it to trigger back the first layer it's basically a hover between two pictures.The thing is i want to do the same with anoter 4 pictures.In total 5 pictures and 10 layers.When the mouse comes across a layer, to trigger layer two and when it leaves the layer the first layer to come back in place making the second layer to dissapear[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it with styles. For instance:

```
.layer_1 {
z-index: 10;
}
.layer_2 {
z-index: 11;
}
.layer_1:hover {
z-index: 12;
}
```

Comment: im asking how i can do this with revolution slider